# iOS How to notify when a new photo added to photo album

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-camera, background-fetch

I have a requirement to send an email whenever a new photo added to the photo album, similar stuff done by IFTTT app, but not getting  any clue for where to start and how to proceed.

I am not sure how iOS background executions will help me for this. Please give me some leads for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: when you add new photo by capture then EXIF data stored for each photo. check out that dictionary and then proceed with Background

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with: detecting a new photo added or sending an email?

Comment: how to detect the new photo entry while application is not in foreground?

Comment: You mean when user Terminated your app and added photo then to notify. If Yes then it's not possible but yes if you want in BACKGROUND then it's possible.

Comment: background execution rite?

Comment: Yes in BACKGROUND